# Partition has become write protected?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I cannot write into a specific partition, which is in the FAT format.
After some searches, I ran the following commands :

```
fdisk -l
```

The output which I got is (loop devices removed):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x63bf98dc

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 207230975 206512128  98.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       207233022 976771071 769538050   367G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       549529600 781461503 231931904 110.6G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6       781463552 976771071 195307520  93.1G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda7       207233024 210161663   2928640   1.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       210163712 393269247 183105536  87.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       393271296 549519359 156248064  74.5G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I also ran another command,

```
gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Output is as :

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 42B6B87A-2653-4F33-95D1-A4E506FEF062
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 22509 sectors (11.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          718847   350.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          718848       207230975   98.5 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
   5       549529600       781461503   110.6 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   6       781463552       976771071   93.1 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
   7       207233024       210161663   1.4 GiB     8200  Linux swap
   8       210163712       393269247   87.3 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   9       393271296       549519359   74.5 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

Please help. Cannot understand what to do.

Comment: Which partition?

Comment: *** 5       549529600       781461503   110.6 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data ***

This is the partition, which is right protected